# How to check if an elasticsearch node runs?

Tags: elasticsearch

Sometimes I found one of my elasticsearch program on a node does not response (hanging) although its pid still exists.

Is there a way to detect this by using any API?

elasticsearch has _cluster/nodes and _cluster/_headth. But I assume the API goes to the master node. Maybe master nodes are busy and return the response of the APIs slowly, which may not mean the current node slow.

Is there a way to check the node status only on the current machine?

Comment: Have you tried using `_cat/health`?

Comment: I tried _cat/health. But I found this API can have a very slow response when I do snapshot although the whole cluster seems working fine. Is the health API sent to the cluster master? Maybe the delay means the cluster master is slow but not the current node is slow.